# Access Rails 3 Session from Rack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-3, rack

I was able to do the following in Rails 2.3.5 to access attributes that I set on the session from within my Rails app.  Now in Rails 3, `env["rack.session"]` is `nil`.  How do I do the same thing in Rails 3?

```
class CallbackFilter
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    unless env["rack.session"][:oauth_callback_method].blank?
      env["REQUEST_METHOD"] = env["rack.session"].delete(:oauth_callback_method).to_s.upcase
    end
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was because I placed the `use CallbackFilter` in `config.ru`.  It should be placed in `config/application.rb` like so:

```
config.middleware.use CallbackFilter
```

Otherwise the environments didn't look like they were in sync...

Answer (score 1):

There's another 'dirty' way to syncronize(for those who can't integrate rack app in rails for some reasons).

You should set :key and :secret to same values in both Rails and Rack.

In rails `:secret` assigned as `ChatApp::Application.config.secret_token` and usually configured in initializers/secret_token.rb , and in session_store.rb there's is a `:key` option for `YourApp::Application.config.session_store`). So in the end it will be something like:

in `Rack::Builder.new` block:

```
use Rack::Session::Cookie, :key => '_your_app_session',
                               :path => '/',
                               :secret => 'secret_more_than_30_dig'
```

initializers/session_store.rb

```
YourApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_your_app_session',
                                                          :path => '/'
```

initializers/secret_token.rb

```
YourApp::Application.config.secret_token = 'secret_more_than_30_dig'
```

now you should be able to access it throw `request.env['rack.session']`

Comment: It work for me. I integrate Rails and Sinatra. Both use same cookie for user auth. Thanks!